# objective-c button target not self

Tags: ios, objective-c, target

I'm making a framework for an iOS app. For this I'm first retrieving the `rootviewcontroller` like this:

```
 _window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
_rootvc = _window.rootViewController;
```

I'm trying to add a simple UIButton to the view of this `viewcontroller` which works great.

```
[_rootvc.view addSubview:_button];
```

However when I click the button, nothing happens even though I set an action like this:

```
[_button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I am sure there is nothing wrong with the method so something must be wrong with the target. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: What does the signature for `buttonClicked` look like?  What kind of object (class) is `self`?  What keeps the `self` object in memory?

Comment: Self is a subclass of an UIViewController, the signature for buttonClicked is
-(void)buttonClicked;
And what exactly do you mean with what keeps self in memory?

Comment: The button is added to the root view controller but the target is a different view controller?  By keeping in memory I mean, is the target view controller part of the active controller hierarchy ... or, how is it created and what owns it?

Comment: Well I first tried to assign the rootviewcontroller to this view controller but it didn't work out so I attempted to use another viewcontroller as target without knowing this was even possible..